# Prove $ \bar{u}\in \operatorname{Hom}_{A} (\operatorname{Hom}(M,N), \operatorname{Hom}(M',N))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am using Atiya-MacDonald, and on page 18 the module homomorphism is explained and expanded on. I understand that based on our definitions of a module homomorphism we can attain an induced map, but I am not sure how to prove the above.  Am I to just verify that $\bar{u}$ is a proper homomorphism? Suppose $u \in \operatorname{Hom}(M',M)$, we associate to this $u$ a map $\bar{u}$ from $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}(M',N)$

If so, I am not sure how to prove that as $$\operatorname{Hom}_{A} (\operatorname{Hom}(M,N),\operatorname{Hom}(M',N)) := \{ \mbox{set of all A-Modules}: \operatorname{Hom}(M,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}(M',N) \}$$

Consider $\phi$ to be an element of the above set, then this means it is a map $\phi(f)= \rule{1cm}{0.15mm}$.

In addition I am asked to prove that if $\Phi$ is a map that takes $u \in \operatorname{Hom}(M',M)$ to $\bar{u},$ then $$\Phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_{A}\Bigg( \operatorname{Hom}(M',M), \operatorname{Hom}\bigg( \operatorname{Hom}(M,N), \operatorname{Hom}(M',N)\bigg) \Bigg)$$

Comment: You should prove that $\bar{u}$ is $A$-linear, i.e. a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u : M' \to M$ is an $A$-module homomorphism. Then $\overline{u} : \text{Hom}(M, N) \to \text{Hom}(M', N)$ is defined by

$$\overline{u}(f) = f \circ u.$$

First, observe that $f \circ u$ is an $A$-module homomorphism from $M'$ to $N$, being a composition of an $A$-module homomorphism from $M'$ to $M$ with an $A$-module homomorphism from $M$ to $N$. So $\overline{u}$ is indeed a map from $\text{Hom}(M, N)$ to $\text{Hom}(M', N)$. Now for $f, g \in \text{Hom}(M, N)$, we have $$\overline{u}(f + g) = (f + g) \circ u = (f \circ u) + (g \circ u) = \overline{u}(f) + \overline{u}(g)$$ by properties of function composition. For $a \in A$, $\overline{u}(af) = af \circ u$; since $f \circ u$ is an element of $\text{Hom}(M', N)$, it follows from the definition of the action of $A$ (which I'll just refer to from now as scalar multiplication) on $\text{Hom}(M', N)$ that $af \circ u = a(f \circ u) = a\overline{u}(f)$. So $\overline{u}$ is an $A$-linear map from $\text{Hom}(M, N)$ to $\text{Hom}(M', N)$.

For your second question, think of $\text{Hom}(M, N)$ and $\text{Hom}(M', N)$ as two $A$-modules $S_1$ and $S_2$. Now just use the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication for the $A$-module $T$ whose elements are the $A$-module homomorphisms from $S_1$ to $S_2$ to see that the map $\Phi$ you've defined is indeed an $A$-module homomorphism from $\text{Hom}(M', M)$ to $T$.